# Indeterminate and field extension

Tags: field-theory

Let M be indeterminate and let K = Q(M) be the field of rational functions in M.
Let $f(x) = x^2 − M$.The problem asks whether $f$ is irreducible. Could someone explain to me what is meant by 'indeterminate' here? I don't know how to use it, can I just interpret it as a transcendental number?

Comment: $K$ is the fraction field of the ring of polynomials with rational coefficients. The variable doesn't have to be interpreted, but yes if you interpret it as a transcendental number then it stays the same field.

Comment: Is M just a variable? Why do we call it indeterminate? Also, how can I relate M with the reducibility of f?

Comment: It can be a variable (ranging over rational or complex numbers), a transcendental number, but in algebra we consider it as "an indeterminate" the same kind as the one appearing in the polynomial ring $\Bbb{Q}[x]$. You shouldn't think to polynomials as functions $\Bbb{Q\to Q}$ but instead as a ring constructed "formally" following some algebraic rules. It is the same for the fraction field $\Bbb{Q}(x)$.

Comment: This is equivalent to showing that $f(x) $ has no roots in $K$. Take any arbitrary element in $K$ of the form $a(M) /b(M) $ and show that its square can't be $M$.